# Вывод натыкается на null хоть его там не должно быть

Tags: c++

Вот моя программа, почему то когда запускаю ее, выводит первые 81 записи, хотя их 400 в базе.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>

#define N 4000

using namespace std;

struct tData
{
    unsigned char street[18];
    short int house;
};

struct List
{
    char name[32];
    union
    {
        tData home;
        unsigned char Digit[sizeof(home)];
    };
    short int flat;
    char data[10];
    List* next;
};

struct Queue
{
    List* head;
    List* tail;
};

void DigitalSort(List*& S) {
    const int L = 4;
    int KDI[L] = { 0, 1, 2, 18 };
    int j, i, k, d;
    List* p;
    Queue* Q = new Queue[256];
    for (j = L - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            Q[i].tail = (List*)&Q[i].head;
        p = S;
        k = KDI[j];
        while (p) {
            d = p->Digit[k];
            Q[d].tail->next = p;
            Q[d].tail = p;
            p = p->next;
        }
        p = (List*)&S;
        for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            if (Q[i].tail != (List*)&Q[i].head) {
                p->next = Q[i].head;
                p = Q[i].tail;
            }
        }
        p->next = NULL;
    }
}

void Run(List*& p, int step) {
    int count = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 80; i++) cout << "#";
    cout << "#                                                                              #";
    while (p && count < 20) {
        printf("# %4d) %32s ", step * 20 + count + 1, p->name);
        printf("%-18s ", p->home.street);
        printf("%-3d ", p->home.house);
        printf("%-4d ", p->flat);
        printf("%-8s #", p->data);
        p = p->next;
        count++;
    }
    cout << "#                                                                              #";
    for (i = 0; i < 80; i++) cout << "#";
    cout << "Do you want to continue?  1/0 : ";
}

int main() {
    system("mode con cols=80 lines=25");
    int i, step = 0, choose;
    fstream file("testBase4.dat", ios::binary | ios::in);
    List* head = new List;
    head = NULL;
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "Could not open the file" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    List* p, * temp;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        p = new List;
        file.read((char*)&p->name, 32);
        file.read((char*)&p->home.street, 18);
        file.read((char*)&p->home.house, sizeof(short int));
        file.read((char*)&p->flat, sizeof(short int));
        file.read((char*)&p->data, 10);
        p->next = head;
        head = p;
    }
    file.close();
    choose = 2;
    DigitalSort(head);
    while (choose != 0 && step < 200) {
        temp = head;
        Run(head, step);
        cin >> choose;
        if (cin.fail()) {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            choose = 2;
            head = temp;
            continue;
        }
        if (choose != 1 && choose != 0) {
            head = temp;
            continue;
        }
        if (choose == 1) step++;
    }
    system("CLS");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ваша **грубая** смена типа `p = (List*)&S;` указывает не на `List` а на указатель на указатель. Делайте всё правильно `p = S ;` Это `(List*)&` у вас три раза сделано.

Comment: после сортировки вы переменную `S` так и не обновили на правильное начало списка.

Comment: Вообще все С-style касты - это грубые ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут трудно сказать, где должен быть `null`, а где нет. Добавьте файл с данными в задачу. А лучше короткий тестовый пример без файла, с заранее определенными входными данными.

Правильно написал @AlexGlebe - вы напутали с приведением типов. Когда вы передаете в качестве параметра функции ссылку на указатель `DigitalSort(List*& S)`, то в теле функции `S` - это уже указатель, имеет тип `List*`. `&S` - это адрес указателя, т.е. будет иметь тип `List**`. А далее вы указатель на указатель насильно (и неправильно) приводите к типу `List*`. Должно быть просто `p = S;`.
Если не смотреть на эту глобальную ошибку, то и других ошибок и недочетов в коде немало.
Не стоит использовать макросы. Используйте константы.

```
// вместо
#define N 4000
// используйте
const int N = 4000;
```

На первых строчках программы - утечка памяти. Выделили память под объект и тут же обнулили указатель!

```
int main() 
{
    List* head = new List;
    head = NULL;
```

Примерно то же самое в функции `DigitalSort()` - память выделили и нигде не удалили. При том, что этот массив используется только в функции сортировки локально.  Чтобы не сильно думать про владение объектами, используйте умные указатели из стандартной библиотеки - `unique_ptr<>` или `shared_ptr<>`. А конкретно в данном случае, т.к. вы знаете размер необходимого массива, не надо его выделять в куче, сделайте локальным, заодно и работать быстрее будет. А для того, чтобы проще было отлавливать ошибки в отладчике, я бы обнулял указатели в массиве.

```
void DigitalSort(List*& S) 
{   // вместо этого
    Queue* Q = new Queue[256];
    // проще вот так
    Queue Q[256];
    // и обнуление
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        Q[i].tail = Q[i].head = nullptr;
}
```

А т.к. это временный массив для сортировки, вам не нужен массив элементов типа `struct Queue`, т.к. `Q[i]->head` нигде не используется. Тут достаточно просто `List* Q[256];`
В функции `Run(List*& p, int step)` вы просто выводите на экран 20 записей. Но зачем-то передаете ссылку на указатель и в результате меняете исходный указатель, когда движетесь по списку. По сути у вас константная функция, не изменяющая внутри себя данные. Передайте в неё указатель по копии `Run(List* p, int step)`.
И с выводом намудрено - проще сделать функцию вывода 1 узла списка, а потом в цикле вывести 20. Чем внутри функции изменять начальный указатель, а потом снаружи функции  возвращать ему первоначальное значение.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20 && p!=NULL; i++)
{  
   Run(p, step); // вывод 1 узла
   p = p->next;
}
```

То же самое внутри функции вы выводите приглашение на ввод `cout << "Do you want to continue?  1/0 : ";`, а сам ввод осуществляется за пределами функции.  Отследить такое поведение - очень сложно.
И с последним циклом для вывода на экран - много заморочек - достаточно просто отследить ввод `0` и закончить цикл. Всё, что не 0 - продолжаем цикл. Или отслеживать 1 - всё остальное - прекратить цикл. Да и работает он криво - если было введено что-то кроме 0 и 1 то будет заново выведено на экран 20 первых записей.
Опять-таки вы не отслеживаете количество введенных записей. В вопросе вы написали что у вас их 400, а в коде используете константу 4000. И при вводе данных из файла в том числе - у вас цикл до 4000 а в файле я так понял всего 400 `for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {`. И не пишите циклы до `магического числа` - всегда надо использовать количество, чтобы избежать ошибки.

```
    while (step * 20 < NumListNode) 
    {
        temp = head;
        Run(head, step);
        cout << "Do you want to continue?  1/0 : ";
        cin >> choose;
        if (choose == 1) 
            step++;
        else
            break;
    }
```

Ну и сама сортировка вызывает множество вопросов. Начиная от выбора структуры данных и заканчивая методом сортировки.
Вообще непонятно зачем вот эта конструкция

```
struct tData
{
    unsigned char street[18];
    short int house;
};
struct List
{
 union
    {
        tData home;
        unsigned char Digit[sizeof(home)];
    };
}
```

Хотите сравнивать по номеру дома - ну и сравнивайте по номеру дома. Сейчас вы пытаетесь сравнивать по младшему байту от `short int house` (для x86 процессоров с little-endian), т.к. `short int` обычно 2 байта.  А если номер дома больше 255? - они все будут сортироваться под номером 255. Если вам точно нужно не более 1 байта под хранение номера дома - используйте `unsigned char`, а ещё лучше `uint8_t`.
А следующие итерации пытаются сравнивать по 3, затем по 2, затем по 1-му символу в названии строки. Что-то очень странная сортировка.
Далее, на первом шаге, элементы массива Q - какой-то случайный мусор. И разыменовывать его - это неопределенное поведение.

```
void DigitalSort(List*& S) 
{
    Queue* Q = new Queue[256];
    for (j = L - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
    {
        ...
        p = S;
        while (p) 
        {
            d = p->Digit[k];
            // вот здесь Q[d].tail не указывает ни на какой объект List
            // в нем - какой-то мусор, допустим 0
            Q[d].tail->next = p;  // получается nullptr->next = p
            Q[d].tail = p;
            p = p->next;
        }
```

В первом цикле вы ваш список разбиваете на 256 отдельных списков, указатель на первый элемент каждого списка хранится в массиве `Queue Q[256]`. А дальше я так понял вы пытаетесь их собрать обратно в один список. Только делаете это неправильно.   И тут начинаются потери элементов и соответственно утечки памяти.
Сначала вы временному указателю присваиваете значение указателя на элемент, который раньше был началом списка. Раньше, S указывал на первый элемент списка, назовем его условно `unit1`. S = `unit1`. И допустим, что у этого элемента номер дома - 200. После первого цикла элемент `unit1` будет висеть в 201 цепочке, привязанной к элементу массива Q[200]. А вы опять делаете его первым p=S=`unit1`. А затем вы этот элемент теряете, т.к. делаете `p->next = Q[i].head; p = Q[i].tail;` А в `Q[i].head` напомню, находится мусор.
Далее, Вам нужно собрать в список все цепочки, которые висят на элементах массива Q. А вы собираете только первые элементы этих цепочек.

```
        p = S; // временное начало списка - на 200 элемент.
        for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)  // проходите по массиву с цепочками
            if (Q[i].tail != Q[i].head) // если цепочка не пустая
            {
                p->next = Q[i].head; // теряете элемент который был началом нового списка
                p = Q[i].tail; // началом нового списка становится первый элемент цепочки, которая была привязана к Q[i]
            } // и переходите на следующую цепочку, вместо того, чтобы пройти по цепочке до последнего элемента.
        p->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

Более того, как написал @AlexGlebe - вы не запомнили начало списка, указатель p начал двигаться дальше по списку.
А на следующей итерации всё повторяется. Сначала вы заполняете массив Q[i] мусором.

```
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    Q[i].tail = Q[i].head;
```

И так по-новой 4 раза. То, что у вас в итоговом списке осталось хоть сколько-то элементов - чистая удача!